# How to restructure Python pandas Dataframe, optimization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a dataset of transactions (40k rows, 45 cols, 11 MB RAM) with ID tracking the whole transaction process (sending, withdrawal, refund) and I need to restructurize Dataframe based on values in column 'Reference number', so that all data tied to this transaction is in one row.

What I do:
load source Dataframe, sort it, iterate row by row to filter occurances of one ID at a time, iterate over final Dataframe columns and assign corresponding value to a local Dictionary.
At the end, concat Dicts and create  a new Dataframe (approx. 1/2 * 40k rows, 69 cols).

Based on my testing, 85 % of required time is consumed by the for loop creating Dict keys (for x, y in dictOfCols.items())
**Is there a better way of doing this?
Currently this script takes more than 30 minutes on a single core AMD Epyc (server) with 8 GB RAM.**

dictOfCols contains pairs of keys (final DF column name) and values (list [source DF columns names]) for 3 possible transaction types  (sending, withdrawal, refund). Shortened example:

```
dictOfCols  = {'reference_number': ['Reference Number', 'Reference Number', 'Reference Number'], 'send_Destination_Country': ['Destination Country', None, None], 'send_ToCountry/Countrpart': ['ToCountry/Countrpart', None, None], 'payout_Destination_Country': [None, 'Destination Country', None], 'payout_ToCountry/Countrpart': [None, 'ToCountry/Countrpart', None], 'bestpay': [None, None, None], 'send': ['Operation', None, None], 'send_DocumentId': ['DocumentId', None, None], 'send_Related_Document_Id': ['Related Document Id', None, None], 'send_Date': ['Date', None, None], 'payout': [None, 'Operation', None], 'payout_documentId': [None, 'DocumentId', None], 'payout_Related_Document_Id': [None, 'Related Document Id', None], 'time_payout': [None, 'Related Document Date', None], 'refund': [None, None, 'Operation'], 'cancelled_time': [None, None, 'Date'], 'send_Point': ['Point', None, None],  ....}
```

DF looks like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OhWu_GrqwZBasuPdGFGynBuDXO7fuBjbFOCjrcIPFis/edit#gid=0
[image]

My code:

```
data = []
df_master = df_master.sort_values(by='Reference Number', axis='index')
df_master = df_master.set_index('Reference Number', drop=False)
df_master = df_master.sort_index()
ref_cols = df_master['Reference Number'].unique().tolist()

for i in ref_cols:
    local = df_master.loc[df_master['Reference Number'] == i]
    if local.empty:
        continue
    # creates slices of local dataframe based on Operation type
    send = local.loc[local['Operation'] == 'SEND']
    payout = local.loc[local['Operation'] == 'PAYOUT']
    refund = local.loc[local['Operation'] == 'REFUND']
    # if len of any DF is more than 1, raise error
    lenCheck([send, payout, refund])

    dict = {}
    # create Dict of one Refenrece number, assign values based on column names from dictOfCols
    for x, y in dictOfCols.items():
        if (y[0] is not None and send.empty == False):
            dict[x] = send.iloc[0][y[0]]  
        elif (y[1] is not None and payout.empty == False):
            dict[x] = payout.iloc[0][y[1]]
        elif (y[2] is not None and refund.empty == False):
            dict[x] = refund.iloc[0][y[2]]
        else:
            dict[x] = False
            # raise ValueError

    data.append(dict)
    df_master.loc[local.index, 'Drop'] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My only idea to speed up the process is to create chunks of source Dataframe and use multiprocessing.

Final Dataframe example:
[image]

Comment: your problem is not clear. please explain what you're doing in the code. Several other questions -  what's dictOfCols here? what's the use of lenCheck here? and what it is?. Plus, don't post the image of output df. use df.to_dict() and post the dict here.

Comment: @Nk03: Can you please elaborate on what is not clear? I seem to had answered all your questions in the original post. The problem is slow inner For loop. dictOfCols is basically a map of column names as described in the post. lenCheck is what the comment says - checks if any of the operation types have contains more than 1 row which it must not as every transaction can only contain max. 1 send, max 1 payout and max 1 refund operation.
Output should contain columns described in dictOfCols object keys and of course corresponding data to those columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that **multiprocessing** sped up the job very much. I just had to split dataframe into 8 chunks on a 8 core CPU.

Also I found out that the script takes 30 minutes only in **debug** mode, not in actual run. Then it takes only about 5 minutes.

Comment: could you please elaborate 
1. how exactly implemented multiprocessing?
2. what you mean by running in debug mode? In VS, Jupyter, terminal?